# Why does as a `(?:)` regex work?

Tags: regex

How is this valid [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) syntax?

```
`(?:)`
```

While `?:` is not.

[fiddle link](http://fiddle.re/43c96)

Excerpt from [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) regarding `?` (question mark):

> Makes the **preceding** item optional. Greedy, so the optional item is
>   included in the match if possible. [emphasis added]

There seems to be no preceding item since the parenthesis `(` is a special character - so not an input character. Also in the fiddle it seems to match the beginning and does not respect the requirement for the `:` (colon) to be there (even though that one is no special character.

Why so? Which documentation section am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(?:…)` is a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) as in opposite to `(…)` whose matched string can be referenced with backreferences.

Comment: Thank you for that reply. However it is not really addressing any of my concerns, so I cannot really mark it as the answer. The provided link however is dead on and I can find my answers, that `(?` is "special syntax", in there.

Comment: @zsawyer How does this not answer your question?

Comment: Maybe I am too picky but I'd like an explicit note that although `?` is a special character, `(?`is overriding special syntax and has nothing to do with the optional indicator `?` which was mentioned in the question.